# URL blocked: This redirect failed and debuging says response status code 401 does not allow login through facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce-3.90

I'm using nopcommerce 3.9 and getting this error I'm not using any plugin for this but I'm using custom code provided by facebook for login. I'm getting the following error :

> URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the
>   client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as
>   valid OAuth redirect URIs.

My redirect uri is : https://mya.abcwebsite.com/dashboard

Also when i debug code I found this error Response status code : 401

I have tried changing my redirect Uri but it didn't work

```
 protected override Task ApplyResponseChallengeAsync()
 {
            var sessionIdlocal = getSessionId();             

            if (Response.StatusCode != 401)
            {
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }
 }
```

Comment: Please avoid posting the Updates for the post as *comments/New Answers* instead [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56537144/edit) your post and update it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link https://developers.facebook.com and added all the possible urls of my domain and sub domain  and turned on the Client 
 1. OAuth Log
 2. Web OAuth Login

in settings for Facebook under App review and my issue is resolved.Only the configuration was needed to redone. :)

Comment: this is the most incomplete answer i have seen, please expand to make this more useful for others.